# Add selected TreeViewNode to DataGridView row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

On select TreeView Node event, a new row in the DataGridView should be added containing some information from the node. But I cannot add a new row to the DataGridView without it replacing the already existing DataGridView row.

The DatagridView columns are named after custom node properties and all row cells must be placed in a column based on the name of the node object property.

This is what I've done so far

```
public static void AddToGrid(TreeNode node, DataGridView gridview)
{
    int rowIndex;
    if (gridview.RowCount > 0)
        rowIndex = gridview.RowCount +1;
    else rowIndex = gridview.Rows.Add();

    var row = gridview.Rows[rowIndex];
    row.Cells["property name"].Value = node.Text;
}
```

When I use this function a new Row is created in the DataGridView. Is there already a row in the DataGridView the existing row get replaced. I want it to add a new Row and also keep existing ones.

**UPDATE**

After hours of search I changed the code trying to figure this out but still same result. The new row replaces the old. The new attempt:

```
public static void AddToGrid(TreeNode node, DataGridView gridview)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
    row.CreateCells(gridview);
    //row.Cells["property name"].Value = node.Text <- stopped working. Error: Cannot find column named "property name". (the column name do exist)
    row.Cells[0].Value = node.Text; // <- Instead I'm using this as for now
    gridview.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: _if (gridview.RowCount > 0)     rowIndex = gridview.RowCount +1;..._ Why that check? You only create one row. If you always want a new one always add one!

Comment: @TaW This function is run every time I select a TreeNode, and it is supposed to add the selected node.Text as a new row in the DataGridView without removing the existing ones. But it replaces existing rows when adding. I figured it could be because the old and new row had the same index.

Comment: The code in the update does not replace anything. It just adds a new row. It you see something else the reason is in some other part of your code..

Comment: @TaW I found the solution to be elsewhere just as you suggested! Big thanks! Post as answer and I will mark it as solution.